# Are C functions slower in .m files than in the .c files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

Are C functions slower in .m files than in the .c files? Does someone know any performance tests?

Comment: are you asking for performance tests between Objective-C and C? C functions have the same performance when used in Objective-C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files are not fast or slow. They are compiled, and linked in a binary. I assume you are asking about the speed of an executable compiled from such files.

The problem is, then, the compiler. If you compile your code from the .c files with the same compiler than the .m files, and it is optimised, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Are C functions slower in .m files than in the .c files? Does someone
>   know any performance tests?

Well, let me sort of interpret your question to mean "Are C-functions slower or faster than Objc-Messages?"  And the answer is....

It depends.  Mike Ash does a great speed comparison between ObjC and C++ and C [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html).